# Strange error with iloc in Pandas: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: javascript, ajax, pandas, csv, flask

I am working on a project with Pandas and Flask and I'm getting this strange error which is the following: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. However, the error itself is not what is strange, what is strange is how it is occurring. I have a flask app with one of the pages being a form that makes an ajax call. The user enters a book title and the average rating of that book is returned. If I type in 'It' then the rating returns. Everything works fine. However, if I type in, The Girl on the Train, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/mikecuddy/Desktop/Coding/Python/book_ratings/app.py", line 75, in book_look_up
    rating = book.book_rating(title)
  File "/Users/mikecuddy/Desktop/Coding/Python/book_ratings/books.py", line 17, in book_rating
    rating = info.iloc[0][12]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1296, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1612, in _getitem_axis
    self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1526, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

However, if I enter in the SAME title into my pandas code, I get the rating! I know that my Pandas code works fine. I'll also say that any book, with a title that has one word, such as It, works fine. It is only with multiple words in the title that my error arises. I have traced the problem to this but cannot get any further. Now my Code:

HTML Code

```
<form class='title_lookUp_div' id='book_look_up_form'>
    <label>Book Title: </label><input id='title' name='title' type='text'>
    <p>Result: <span id='result'>?</span></p>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS/AJAX Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#book_look_up_form').bind('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        data: {
          title: $('#title').val()
        },
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/book_look_up',
       success: function(data){
       $('#result').text(data.result).show();
      }
    });
   });
  });
```

Pandas Code:

```
    def book_rating(self, title):
       #Gettting the row of data for the title that the user entered.
       info = self.__data[self.__data.original_title == title]
       rating = info.iloc[0][12]
       return rating
```

app.py code:

```
@app.route('/book_look_up',methods=['POST'])
def book_look_up():
   #Recieving the data from the ajax call
   title = request.form['title']
   #The data in the CSV file has the first letter of each word capitalized 
   title = title.title()
   #Creating the object that will deal with the data from CSV file.
   book = Books()
   rating = book.book_rating(title)
   if title: 
      return jsonify(result = rating)
   return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing Data'})
```

Like I said, the Pandas code works fine, the app.py and ajax call is working fine. It is just when the data has multiple words in it that everything crashes and I get above error message. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: What's the value of `info` in the pandas code when it crashes?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the value of info is: Empty DataFrame. However, I'm pretty sure that the error is mine-what is typed in has to match exactly what is in the CSV file. So I had the .title() method turning The Girl on the Train into the Girl On The Train when it should be the former! Have to figure out a better way to get a match!

Comment: Thus, I've realized that my error is about getting the user input to match what is in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

After much review, it turns out that this is a regex issue. Please see my comments above. In this example, my problems were coming from the .title() method which was changing how the title was being searched for within the CSV file.